# Will there be a Vala template for quickly?

Tags: development, application-development, quickly, vala

Are there plans to develop a Vala template for Quickly? Would be interesting because I think, Vala will be the next gen programming language for Gnome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a quickly Vala template is indeed [starting to take shape](http://shanefagan.com/quickly-vala-template-starting-to-take-shape/).

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: You might also want to look into creating a new template http://askubuntu.com/questions/136850/how-to-create-a-new-quickly-application-template