# Is Quickly a Python-only development tool?

Tags: python, application-development, quickly

I'm looking at the Ubuntu app development tool Quickly. From what I can see only Python is available with this tool. Is this correct or are other languages like Java (and others) also available?

Answer (score 3):

Quickly is extensible to provide a template infrastructure to allow the use of different technologies, but right now the `ubuntu-application` template is based on Python and GTK+.

You can see more detail on the technologies it puts together here:

- [Getting started with Quickly](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/)
- [Quickly workflow](http://developer.ubuntu.com/quickly-workflow)

That said, the flexibility of Quickly's template system makes it easy for anyone to create new templates with other technology choices. Check these out:

- [How to create a new Quickly template](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136850/how-to-create-a-new-quickly-application-template)
- [Quickly community templates](https://launchpad.net/quickly-community-templates)

On the last link you'll see that there is work in progress to extend the core set of templates to provide apps based on different tech, such as an HTML5 app, or a Qt app, but until they're finished, the recommendation is to use the `ubuntu-application` template based on Python and GTK.