# How do I add a daemon to my Quickly application?

Tags: python, application-development, quickly, services

I am building a app with [quickly](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Quickly), and I wanted to add a daemon that will run in the background. How do you do this?

Comment: You should take a look at D-Bus.

Comment: Please provide a link to the quickly homepage. With a name like that one cannot google it.

Comment: What is this deamon supposed to do? Does it need to be public or just for your application?

Comment: @dotancohen Done. Although I'd suggest the import bit is that it's in Python.

Comment: @Timo I can't speak for Vigesh, but for my bounty I'm looking at something just for my application

Comment: @Timo The daemon is currently, only for my application,but Later I might decide to make it public.
ps: fluteflute thanks for putting the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

As far I know there is nothing specific in quickly to prevent or assist you with running daemons, but there is at least two options I know/guess you can do it with python:

### Option #1: Distutils

*NOTE: I didn't tried this one yet :)*

1. put your daemon script into the `bin` directory of your quickly project, e.g.: `bin/yourapp-launcher`
2. add the following into the `data/yourapp-launcher.desktop` file:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Your App
   Exec=/bin/sh -c 'yourapp-launcher'
   Type=Application
   X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=30
   Icon=yourapp
   Comment=
   NoDisplay=true
   ```
3. edit `setup.py` and specify additional `data_files` in DistUtilsExtra section, e.g.:

   ```
   DistUtilsExtra.auto.setup(
   name='hello-ubuntu',
   version='0.1',
   #license='GPL-3',
   #author='Your Name',
   #author_email='email@ubuntu.com',
   #description='UI for managing â¦',
   #long_description='Here a longer description',
   #url='https://launchpad.net/hello-ubuntu',
   cmdclass={'install': InstallAndUpdateDataDirectory},
   data_files=[('/etc/xdg/autostart', ['data/yourapp-launcher.desktop'])]
   )
   ```

Seems a way to go when daemon must be running for all users, e.g. similar how U1 works.

### Option #2: Hardcode

Hardcode everything into your app logic, for example initialize ~/.config/autostart/yurapp-launcher.desktop on the first run, e.g. similar to how [GmailNotify App](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~gm-notify-maintainers/gm-notify/trunk/view/head:/gm-notify-config#L117) does it.

Unlike GmailNotify App you can relie on the [python-xdg](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-xdg) library to access freedesktop.org standards:

```
import xdg
print xdg.BaseDirectory.xdg_config_home
```

Seems good for user managed daemons.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see there is no template to add a daemon in quickly. However, you can contribute by creating a daemon template. How to create your own template is explained in the answer to this question: [How to create a new quickly application template](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136850/how-to-create-a-new-quickly-application-template)

You could also join the [community templates group](https://launchpad.net/quickly-community-templates) at Launchpad, to make your template available for others to use.

EDIT: There is also the [Unity lens template](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/amd64/quickly-unity-lens-template). It will only work with Ubuntu Unity, so you will be platform dependent (rather significant weakness if you ask me). But it seems to have D-Bus things ready from the start. Kind of like a daemon, but maybe not quite. You could use this as a starting-point to create a platform independent daemon, perhaps...

I don't know any details other than what I can link from others, sorry. Just looking at this myself to find out how to use Qt4 with quickly. EDIT2: Just found that there is a D-Bus component to Qt, which would make your daemon platform independent (working on Windows and Linux etc). This discussion forum (http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/38453-Send-and-receive-a-signal-between-2-Qt-applications) has an example (in C++, but still) of how to use it. Or you can google for QDBusConnection and QDBusMessage.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the Quickly docs, it seems that Quickly does not natively support creating daemons. Therefore I suggest the [Python Daemon Library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/). Also, go over the following Python tutorials that could be interfaced easily from a Quickly application:

- [Writing a Python Daemon](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/)
- [A simple unix/linux daemon in Python](http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/)
- [Creating a daemon the Python way](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/278731-creating-a-daemon-the-python-way/)

Also, [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473620/how-do-you-create-a-daemon-in-python) addresses Python daemons.

Comment: I have gone through many of the links, but I am looking for a recommended way to connect my quickly GUI app and a daemon that will run in parallel.The daemon has to be packaged with the same app and should be started on boot.

Comment: Again, Quickly does not support this. You will have to graduate the application from Quickly to 'real' Python. That is why I provided the example links.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.3 will have a daemon module for the management of daemons.