# How to add a daemon to a quickly project

Tags: python, quickly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add a daemon to my Quickly application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157108/how-do-i-add-a-daemon-to-my-quickly-application)

Currently I'm developing an application with quickly which is divided in two parts:

1. A *graphical UI* where the user could configure some things,
2. and a *daemon* which do the most work in the background.

I started with the UI, to create some windows for settings and so on. Now I want to start coding the daemon, but I have no clue **how to implement the daemon in my quickly project**.

Could I simply paste the files of the daemon in project folder or is there an implementation method for adding new files to a quickly project? Or do I have to create a new project and merge them together?