# How to configure quickly with java?

Tags: application-development, java, quickly

I want to use java instead of python in quickly. Is this possible? I actually don't know much python and so I have chosen java as my language for making a software.

Comment: the most popular solution when dealing with an application written in 1 language when the destination platform is supporting another one, is to write a wrapper in the platform language that will launch the main application.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry , java templates are not yet available for quickly . If you are interested you can create java template quickly and share with us

Comment: i would love to help the linux community ... but i don't know how to go about it ... can you please help me with that ??

Comment: @PranitBauva Check out this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/136850/how-to-create-a-new-quickly-application-template