# How can I use Ruby with Quickly?

Tags: application-development, quickly, ruby

Recently I came across [Quickly](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/tools/quickly/). A very nice thing Ubuntu is doing in order to simplify creation of good looking applications that integrates well with Ubuntu desktop in every respect.

While the [demo](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/) was so cool and even motived me to learn Python, I am only familiar with Ruby. I would really love if there is a way to make Quickly do similar thing with Ruby.

I read something about templates; but couldn't locate much details.

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible as Quickly is only designed to generate and compile Python applications.

Comment: There's a stale project from 2010 and templates for quickly-ruby located here https://code.launchpad.net/~antono/quickly/ruby-templates - other than that. I was unable to locate anything helpful.

Comment: @lazyPower Thanks for trying to look around for useful info. I found that too. But I got no clue what so ever. I thought somebody in-the-know could post some useful info since it is no where to find.

Comment: http://blog.didrocks.fr/index.php/post/Build-your-application-quickly-with-Quickly:-Inside-Quickly-part-6 has some basic information about how to create a new template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to use Ruby with Quickly. However, the good news is that Quickly has a flexible templating system that enables you to create templates for new types of applications or languages.

Thus you can create a Ruby template by following [this guide on a previous Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/a/136855/9781).

I can see two previous attempts at creating Ruby templates, but it seems the authors lost interested or did not have time to continue development. Perhaps you can pick it up from there or use them as a basis for a new Quickly Ruby template:

- [Ruby templates](https://code.launchpad.net/~antono/quickly/ruby-templates)
- [Quickly Ruby](https://launchpad.net/quickly-ruby)